# Google Driver APi error 403 in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

In my android app I need to use the Google Driver API to upload and download files. I am using this code

```
Files.List request = service.files().list();
request.setQ("title = '" + FilePathUtils.PHONE_DIR_PATH
FileList files = request.execute();
```

but sometimes an exception occurs:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden W/System.err( 7009): {
> W/System.err( 7009):   "code": 403,
> W/System.err( 7009):   "errors": [
> W/System.err( 7009):     { 
> W/System.err( 7009):       "domain": "usageLimits",
> W/System.err( 7009):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
> W/System.err( 7009):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
> W/System.err( 7009):     }
> W/System.err( 7009):   ],
> W/System.err( 7009):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
> W/System.err( 7009): }
```

I have done this:

1. Enable Google API and SDK in API console
2. API key configuration is correct in the API console
3. client id has been created in the API console

The exception is raised sometimes, but sometimes it works well. Am I ignoring some configuration or the Google API is too old?

Need your assistance, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable logging and look at the request URL to see what is different. You're checking that the ID and Authorization header is set correctly.

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable logging and check authorization header in detail,

Comment: The API library is in turn built on the the http-java-client library. Enabling logging is documented here https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Android#Logging